# Which file/template is in charge of taxonomies for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, templates

I have set up a CPT, lets say "Movies".

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug'=>'movies', 'with_front'=>FALSE )
```

I added a taxonomy "Genre".

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug'=>'movies/genre', 'with_front'=>FALSE )
```

I also tried

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug'=>'genre', 'with_front'=>TRUE )

register_taxonomy( 'category_movie', 'movie', $args );
```

Everything works, but, when I want to browse some movies e.g. in the category/taxonomy horror it does not work.

I assumed the file taxonomy-category_movie.php and if not then taxonomy.php

OR

category.php

OR

tag.php

BUT NO! WP always falls back to the index.php file.

So I though I will check what WP actually is doing and added

```
if ( is_home() )
{
echo "<br>IS HOME";
}

if ( is_single() )
{
 echo "<br>IS SINGLE";
}

if ( is_singular() )
{
 echo "<br>IS SINGULAR";
}

if ( is_front_page() )
{
 echo "<br>IS FRONT PAGE";
}

if ( is_page() )
{
 echo "<br>IS PAGE";
}

if ( is_category() )
{
 echo "<br>IS CATEGORY";
}

if ( is_tag() )
{
 echo "<br>IS TAG";
}

if ( is_tax() )
{
 echo "<br>IS TAX";
}
```

but none of the messages made it into the browser....

Hopefully somebody knows the answer!!

Answer (score 2):

There's a giant diagram on the wordpress documentation showing how it chooses which file to display/load, as you can see here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png

[image]

If this doesn't help, my other suggestion is trying with the '_' removed from the taxonomy name, and to test with the rewrite option removed from your custom post type declaration. In my experience wordpress is fidgetty about type names that add punctuation so I try to keep to a singular word or Camel case. You may have more success with a "genre" taxonomy